# Задать стиль для двух кнопок по условию url

Tags: html, css, jquery, razor

У меня есть две кнопки на странице b1 и b2.

1) Как задать стиль .st для b1, если текущий url страницы равен /addsession? или /order/attrorders? (стиль для b2 убрать)

2) стиль .st если текущий url равен /addrequest? (для b1 убрать)

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/selektory-atributov

Comment: А у вас что, разные урлы обрабатываются одним контроллером и, соответственно, отдаётся одна и та же вьюха?

Comment: в первом случае первый url это контроллер 1, вторая url контроллер 2..во втором случае контроллер тоже 1, но с другим параметром.

Comment: видимо можно использовать поиск jquery $('a[href="' + window.location.pathname + '"]')....   только вот как получить этот этот же путь до символа "?"

Comment: Каким боком тут jquery? В метках его вообще нет (как и javascript). Изначально вопрос поставлен так, что нужно менять стили во view.

Comment: задача именно применить стиль по определенному url.. думал сделать средствами razor, но видимо с jquery было бы поизящнее... нужно найти элемент с ссылкой на странице по текущему url и задать стиль... причем поиск должен быть НЕ равен текущей ссылке, а содержит... извините за теги

Comment: Вот именно что с помощью razor это делается изящно и непринужденно. Какие у вас возникли проблемы, я не понимаю. Каждому урлу соответствует свой контроллер и своя вьюха, в которой устанавливается нужный стиль. Всё. Это азы aps.net mvc, описаны в каждом первом учебнике.

Comment: разобрался.. может кому-то будет полезно $('a[href *= "' + url + '"]').children("button").attr("style", "background: #eec15b;"); если кто-то напишет как при помощи razor сделать красиво, будет полезно.. но задача решена..

Comment: Не пишите ответ в комментариях! Оформите полноценный ответ (и примите его потом).

Comment: Стало быть, смена стиля делается на фронтенде. То есть это не имеет никакого отношения к бэкенду и razor вообще не при чём. И остаётся непонятным, при чём тут url: ведь не происходит переход по нему на другую страницу?

Comment: Верно, только front. Именно поэтому я и решил что тут нужен jquery. Просто для интереса наверное знаю как это реализовать через razor. Но будет больше кода, а это ни к чему. Url нужен только как критерий  поиска для селектора (на странице есть кнопка с ссылкой которую ищет jquery)